# Fields of my model not being set MEAN stack

Tags: javascript, passport.js, mean-stack

Here you can see my API controller method:

```js
//need to export the api methods.
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var User = require('../models/user');
var crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports.create = function(req, res) {

  //TODO: error checking.
  var user = new User();
  user.firstName = req.body.firstName;
  user.lastName = req.body.secondName;
  user.email = req.body.email;
  user.salt = crypto.randomBytes(16).toString('hex');
  user.password = crypto.pbkdf2Sync(req.body.password, user.salt, 1000, 64).toString('hex');
  //console.log(user);
  user.save(function(err) {
    res.status(200);
  });
};
```

Here is my model:

```js
var mongoose = require('mongoose');
var crypto = require('crypto');

module.exports = mongoose.model('User', {
  email: {
    type: String,
    unique: true,
    required: true
  },
  firstName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  lastName: {
    type: String,
    required: true
  },
  hash: String,
  salt: String
});
```

Strangely enough even though my req.body contains all the information that I am trying to set, when I log the user at the end the only things that seem to be getting set are the first name and the salt?

Does anyone know why this is? And could you show me the correct way to do it?

Thanks

Comment: Well, I don't have an answer, but a few ideas comes to mind. First. Output the `err` in your save callback. Where do you check your req.body? Are you sure you are not using some body-parser that moves data to req.user or req.params or whatnot?  "seem to be getting set" also sounds really vague. Have you had a look in the database to see if the data is really there? Sorry if it's all obvious things, but it seems as if you must have missed something pretty obvious.  Have you restarted your server after making changes? Auto-restart?

Comment: Maybe serialize your data, Json.stringify() on set.

Comment: "strict option may also be set to "throw" which will cause errors to be produced instead of dropping the bad data."  try to determine why mongo wont persist the data `mongoose.model('User', {...}, 'throw')` I would also double check your strings as mentioned above

Comment: Hi I've tried logging user after each of the assignments, and it was always like {firstName: blah}, until I assign the salt, then it was {firstName: blah, salt: foobar}

Comment: The err says "lastname is required and email are required", which confirms that both the firstname and salt are being set correctly. Yes I have been restarting the server. And I'm using body-parser. have done console.log(req.body) and get "{firstName: blah, lastName: foo, email:foo@bar.com, password: myLittlePony}"

Comment: Weirdly enough when I do var user = new User(req.body), then it sets the first name and the last name but nothing else. Would it be useful if I posted more code?

Comment: I think when youre calling `new User();` its requiring the fields. kinda a long shot but try to create the user by calling `User(userObject).save()` where userObject is just the fields and values not a new model